# cross total of a std_logic_vector

Tags: vhdl

My purpose of this code is a cross total of a std_logic_vector.
I have the following code:

```
generic(
        lowPass_len : integer := 4;
```

...

```
signal inputbuffer : std_logic_vector(lowPass_len-1 downto 0);
signal sum: integer range 0 to lowPass_len;
signal lowpass_alarm_tog : std_logic;
```

...

```
inputbuffer <= inputbuffer(lowPass_len-1 downto 1) & alarm_tog_d2_meta;
for i in (lowPass_len-1) downto 1 loop
            sum <= to_integer(unsigned(inputbuffer(i-1)) + unsigned(inputbuffer(i)));
        end loop;
```

because inputbuffer is a std_logic_vector, I wanted to cast it to unsigned to make the addition. then convert it to integer, as sum has this kind of type.

ghdl gives me the following mistake for two times in this line

> conversion not allowed between not closely related types

Comment: With values comprised of binary digits it's generally called 'popcount' after machine instructions on big iron influenced by the NSA. An example can be seen in the second process in Bill Lynch's answer  to [Non-static loop limit exceeded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14789278/non-static-loop-limit-exceeded/14790599#14790599) (without the clocking).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `inputbuffer(i-1)` just returns a single bit of type `std_logic`. This cannot be directly casted to `unsigned` because the latter is an array of `std_logic`.

You have to extend the single bit to a vector of the required length first. The length depends on the highest number which could be encountered in the addition.